# How to add description attribute while generating JSON schema from POJOs using codehaus package classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, fasterxml

I intend to convert my `POJO`s to a `JSON Schema`.

In the existing `POJO`s we have annotations from the `codehaus` package:
`@JsonProperty("address")` where the corresponding import is:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
```

I can't use `codehaus` api to generate the schema as we have a recursive `JSON` structure and I get `StackOverflowError`.

So, I tried using the `fasterxml`'s `jackson-module-jsonschema` `API` to do this which works fine.

Sample output that I'm getting:

```
"Registration" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:xyz.abc.Address",
}
```

I have two requirements:

- Apart from "type" and "id", I also want to have a description attribute. I can add `@JsonPropertyDescription` attribute, which would work, but then each property will have one annotation from `codehaus` and another one from the `fasterxml` package. Is there an equivalent annotation in `codehaus` which can be used for this purpose?
- Is there a way to have just the un-qualified class name in the "id" attribute (only "Address" i.e. without the qualified object path "xyz.abc.Address" and without "urn:jsonschema") ?

Code for schema generation using `fasterxml`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(DashboardDef.class);
String generatedJsonSchema = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Did below answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible just replace `codehaus` annotation by `fasterxml` one. `codehaus` is not supported anymore and should be avoided. For more info take a look at: [org.codehaus.jackson versus com.fasterxml.jackson.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core).

If you really want to dive into project with these two libraries you should take a look at [AnnotationIntrospector](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/AnnotationIntrospector) class which allow extra configuration and linking many different libraries with `Jackson` framework. See similar question: [How to make fasterxml ObjectMapper work with codehaus annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955623/how-to-make-fasterxml-objectmapper-work-with-codehaus-annotations).

To manipulate `JSON Schema` you can implement your own [SchemaFactoryWrapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jsonSchema/factories/SchemaFactoryWrapper.java). See also:

- [Removing “id” from JSON schema when creating it from POJO using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114170/removing-id-from-json-schema-when-creating-it-from-pojo-using-jackson/50334845).
- [Generating flat JSON schema with all $ref resolved from Java class #132](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/issues/132)

PS: I know this is not ideal answer (it does not contain direct solution) but I wanted point you some topics which you should start from to solve your problems, and comments are too small for this.